# Jenkins - are both .org and .io official Jenkins websites?

Tags: jenkins

What's the difference between the `.org` and `.io` domains behind Jenkins?

E.g. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org

and https://jenkins.io/

E.g. are they both `official` Jenkins sites?

Comment: Note that https://jenkins.io/ links in its top menu to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org (Resources->Wiki)

Comment: They are both linked to the same person in the SOA DNS.

`tyler@monkeypox.org`

Comment: Both are official — jenkins-ci.org is the original domain name, but the project got jenkins.io last year and is slowly moving things there, but many services (e.g. wiki, bug tracker) are still on the original domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> E.g. are they both official Jenkins sites?

Yes.

> What's the difference between the .org and .io domains behind Jenkins?

the first one is only a wiki and the second one is a website where the tool is promoted and provides some more tools